# Can't open a screen on pty freshly created

Tags: gnu-screen, pty

I have a program that communicates through a serial protocol `uart`. I would like to test this protocol using `simple terminal emulator` running on the same computer.

This program opens `/dev/tty`. I would like to open terminal emulator (like screen, kermit or something else) to communicate with the program using the same `tty`.

A representation to my idea above is as follows:

`<terminal> --> /dev/tty <--- <program to test>`

Practically speaking, my idea was to open `/dev/ptmx` with a terminal emulator, then open the corresponding `/dev/pts/x` with my program to do it, but it seems to be hard to achieve.

*More clarification about what I tried:*

When I open terminal on `/dev/ptmx` using this command :

```
screen /dev/ptmx 115200
```

It creates a file called `7` in the following path `/dev/pts/7`. I can't open this file using the command:

```
$ screen /dev/pts/7 115200
[screen is terminating]
```

Or even the command `cat` can not open it :

```
$ cat /dev/pts/7
cat: /dev/pts/7: Input/output error
```

Also, I tried the command `stty -F` which could not open it as well!:

```
$ stty -F /dev/pts/7
stty: /dev/pts/7: Input/output error
```

How can I get two screens to communicate with each other using `pty`?

Comment: screen's intended use will create a new slave pty each time you attach to a session.

Comment: but how can I open the new slave pty with another screen ?

Comment: screen won't do it, because it doesn't behave like a pty master :-)

Comment: Is there a tty terminal that can act as a pty master ?

Comment: Pretty much all of them can and do, because using pseudo terminals and handling their master sides is part and parcel of being a terminal emulator (except in the cases of those built into kernels) or mux. You seem confused about what you actually want. Your actual goal is certainly not stated in the question, and people are having difficulty with your question because your chosen means of achieving your goal is nonsensical. [Put down the chocolate-covered banana, step away from the currency systems](http://jdebp.info./FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html), and _explain the goal_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to do the communication using the project [`tty0tty`](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty):

Once a kernel module is loaded into Linux `/dev/tntx`, the `tty` devices will appear. We just had managed a connection of one program to `/dev/tntn`, and the `screen/kermit/..` on `/dev/tnt(n+1)` and that worked.